# How to get every possible combination base on the ranges in brackets?

Tags: c#, python

Looking for the best way to take something like `1[a-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]` and have it output a log that would look like the following — basically every possible combination base on the ranges in brackets.

```
1a3107R
1a3107E
1a3107F
1a3107G
1b3107R
1b3107E
1b3107F
1b3107G
1c3107R
1c3107E
1c3107F
1c3107G
```

all the way to `1C3607G`.

Sorry for not being more technical about what I looking for, just not sure on the correct terms to explain.

Comment: Please explain how you are doing it now and in what way you are looking to improve your current solution.

Comment: put the values in arrays and use nested loops to loop through all possibilities

Comment: What values fall within `a-C`? I assume just alphabetic characters, especially since the ASII value of `a` is larger than that of `C`. If you make some rules about the ranges, you can write a helper method that gets all characters from a range and returns them in an array, then you just loop through them.

Comment: What format is something like `1[a-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]` in, a string?

Comment: Is `1[a-C]3` equivalent to `1[A-C]3` and `1[A-c]3`?

Comment: C# or python? They are very different

Answer (score 0):

Normally what we'd do to get all combinations is to put all our ranges into arrays, then use nested loops to loop through each array, and create a new item in the inner loop that gets added to our results.

But in order to do that here, we'd first need to write a method that can parse your range string and return a list of `char` values defined by the range. I've written a rudimentary one here, which works with your sample input but should have some validation added to ensure the input string is in the proper format:

```
public static List<char> GetRange(string input)
{
    input = input.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    var parts = input.Split(',');
    var range = new List<char>();

    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        var ends = part.Split('-');

        if (ends.Length == 1)
        {
            range.Add(ends[0][0]);
        }
        else if (char.IsDigit(ends[0][0]))
        {
            var start = Convert.ToInt32(ends[0][0]);
            var end = Convert.ToInt32(ends[1][0]);
            var count = end - start + 1;
            range.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(start, count).Select(c => (char) c));
        }
        else
        {
            var start = (int) ends[0][0];
            var last = (int) ends[1][0];
            var end = last < start ? 'z' : last;

            range.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1)
                .Select(c => (char) c));

            if (last < start)
            {
                range.AddRange(Enumerable.Range('A', last - 'A' + 1)
                    .Select(c => (char) c));
            }
        }
    }

    return range;
}
```

Now that we can get a range of values from a string like `"[a-C]"`, we need a way to create nested loops for each range, and to build our list of values based on the input string.

One way to do this is to replace our input string with one that contains placeholders for each range, and then we can create a loop for each range, and on each iteration we can replace the placeholder for that range with a character from the range.

So we'll take an input like this: `"1[a-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]"`, and turn it into this: `"1{0}3{1}07{2}"`. Now we can create loops where we take the characters from the first range and create a new string for each one of them, replacing the `{0}` with the character. Then, for each one of those strings, we iterate over the second range and create a new string that replaces the `{1}` placeholder with a character from the second range, and so on and so on until we've created new strings for every possible combination.

```
public static List<string> GetCombinatins(string input)
{
    // Sample input = "1[a-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]"
    var inputWithPlaceholders = string.Empty;   // This will become "1{0}3{1}07{2}"
    var placeholder = 0;
    var ranges = new List<List<char>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // We've found a range start, so replace this with our 
        // placeholder '{n}' and add the range to our list of ranges
        if (input[i] == '[')
        {
            inputWithPlaceholders += $"{{{placeholder++}}}";
            var rangeEndIndex = input.IndexOf("]", i);
            ranges.Add(GetRange(input.Substring(i, rangeEndIndex - i)));
            i = rangeEndIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            inputWithPlaceholders += input[i];
        }
    }

    if (ranges.Count == 0) return new List<string> {input};

    // Add strings for the first range
    var values = ranges.First().Select(chr =>
        inputWithPlaceholders.Replace("{0}", chr.ToString())).ToList();

    // Then continually add all combinations of other ranges
    for (int i = 1; i < ranges.Count; i++)
    {
        values = values.SelectMany(value =>
            ranges[i].Select(chr =>
                value.Replace($"{{{i}}}", chr.ToString()))).ToList();
    }

    return values;
}
```

Now with these methods out of the way, we can create output of all our ranges quite easily:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetCombinatins("1[a-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]")));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem in three stages. The first stage is to transform the source string to an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ParseSourceToEnumerables(string source);
```

For example the source `"1[A-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]"` should be transformed to the 6 enumerables below:

```
"1"
"A", "B", "C"
"3"
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
"07"
"R", "E", "F", "G"
```

Each literal inside the source has been transformed to an `IEnumerable<string>` containing a single string.

The second stage would be to create the Cartesian product of these enumerables.

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
```

The final (and easiest) stage would be to concatenate each one of the inner `IEnumerable<string>` of the Cartesian product to a single string. For example
the sequence `"1", "A", "3", "1", "07", "R"` to the string `"1A3107R"`

The hardest stage is the first one, because it involves parsing. Below is a partial implementation:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ParseSourceToEnumerables(string source)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"\[(.*?)\]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    int previousIndex = 0;
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var previousLiteral = source.Substring(
            previousIndex, match.Index - previousIndex);
        if (previousLiteral.Length > 0)
            yield return Enumerable.Repeat(previousLiteral, 1);
        yield return SinglePatternToEnumerable(match.Groups[1].Value);
        previousIndex = match.Index + match.Length;
    }
    var lastLiteral = source.Substring(previousIndex, source.Length - previousIndex);
    if (lastLiteral.Length > 0) yield return Enumerable.Repeat(lastLiteral, 1);
}

static IEnumerable<string> SinglePatternToEnumerable(string pattern)
{
    // TODO
    // Should transform the pattern "X,A-C,YZ"
    // to the sequence ["X", "A", "B", "C", "YZ"]
}
```

The second stage is hard too, but solved. I just grabbed the implementation from [Eric Lippert's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
        accumulator.SelectMany(_ => sequence,
            (accseq, item) => accseq.Append(item)) // .NET Framework 4.7.1
    );
}
```

The final stage is just a call to [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join).

```
var source = "1[A-C]3[1-6]07[R,E-G]";
var enumerables = ParseSourceToEnumerables(source);
var combinations = CartesianProduct(enumerables);
foreach (var combination in combinations)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Combination: {String.Join("", combination)}");
}
```